# function for dividing data frame into segments in R

Tags: r, subset

I am working with a large data set that has a time column and a wind speed column.  I need to find a way to divide the data frame into smaller segments based off the time comlumn.  if my data frame is

```
hrmin    wind
1100     x1
1100     x2
1100     x3
1101     x4
1101     x5
1101     x6
1102     x7
1102     x8
1102     x9
1103     x10
1103     x11
1103     x12
```

I need a function to divide it into smaller segments then output those segments.  If I wanted to divide it into two segments then my result is

```
df1
1100     x1
1100     x2
1100     x3
1101     x4
1101     x5
1101     x6

df2
1102     x7
1102     x8
1102     x9
1103     x10
1103     x11
1103     x12
```

If I need to output four data frames then I would have

```
df1
1100     x1
1100     x2
1100     x3

df2
1101     x4
1101     x5
1101     x6

df3
1102     x7
1102     x8
1102     x9

df4
1103     x10
1103     x11
1103     x12
```

I imagine I would need a function that incorporates split() and subset() but I am not sure how to build it.  I am thinking something along the lines of

```
function( full data frame,number of segments I need) {

split(full data frame, subset(time segments))
return(appropriate amount of smaller data frames)

}
```

Is there a way to do this or perhaps something better than making a function? I have found ways that show the smaller data frames but I ideally would like them returned with a  name like df1, df2, df3... so I can work on them individually after they have output

Comment: I came up with this `split(df1, (cumsum(!duplicated(df1$hrmin))-1)%/%n+1)` If we specify `n <-1`, it will split by each unique `hrmin`, changing to `n <- 2`, by two 'hrmin', same as your output.  But as @Frank mentioned earlier in the comments, suppose if you have 5 unique 'hrmin', how do you want to split by 3.  In the above approach, it will first split the 3 unique hrmin in one list element and 2 in the next list element.

Comment: I used 3 hrmin in the example but my real data set has many more.  Each group needs to be identified by the hrmin.  I need to assign all hrmin that are 1100 and 1101 to df1 and all hrmin that are 1102 and 1103 to df2.  I think @Frank offers a good point and is able to point me in the right direction

Comment: @user2113499 Fyi, unless you are parallellizing your computations (using your computer and fancy/advanced tools to run the computations on multiple data.frames at the same time), you probably do not want to split the data.frame up in this way.

Comment: So the data is at 20 hz but I made my times just show the hour and minute and what I am trying to do is take the average of certain time frames.  So in one data frame I can have all the 1100 and 1101 data points and in another df I have 1102 and 1103. For each df I would take the average wind speed. Then I would do this again but with 4 data frames.  It's to demonstrate the importance of choosing the correct time scale for averaging.

Comment: It's not necessary to have separate data frames for that. You can make a grouping variable for each case and then aggregate on it, using `aggregate` or the data.table or dplyr packages. If you post something more like your application (in a separate question), I bet someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

This is very similar to @akrun's answer (maybe currently deleted):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DT)

DT[, g := .GRP, by=hrmin]
split(DT, findInterval(
  DT$g, 
  seq(1, uniqueN(DT$hrmin), length.out = n + 1), 
  rightmost.closed = TRUE 
))
```

It splits up the groups in order, simply based on the number of groups (and ignoring the number of rows in each group). You can vary `n` to see how it works. It's straightforward to put this into a function. It's also not hard to do this without [`data.table`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started); it is simply used here for its nice shortcuts:

- `uniqueN(DT$hrmin)` is the number of values for the grouping variable.
- `.GRP, by=hrmin` is an ID for the grouping variable, counting `1..uniqueN(DT$hrmin)`.